# Cross-platform performance testing tool

Tags: hardware, performance, testing

I want to compare operating systems by performance on my hardware. Is there a cross-platform tool for doing it?

I need results of CPU and graphics performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/) which is one of the most widely used performance measuring tool, and runs on Linux, FreeBSD, Windows, Mac OS X, etc.

Here is a description from their website:

> The Phoronix Test Suite is the most comprehensive testing and
> benchmarking platform available that provides an extensible framework
> for which new tests can be easily added. The software is designed to
> effectively carry out both qualitative and quantitative benchmarks in
> a clean, reproducible, and easy-to-use manner.
>
> Originally developed for automated Linux testing, **support to the
> Phoronix Test Suite has since been added for OpenSolaris, Apple Mac OS
> X, Microsoft Windows, and BSD operating systems**. The Phoronix Test
> Suite consists of a lightweight processing core (pts-core) with each
> benchmark consisting of an XML-based profile and related resource
> scripts. The process from the benchmark installation, to the actual
> benchmarking, to the parsing of important hardware and software
> components is heavily automated and completely repeatable, asking
> users only for confirmation of actions.

Answer (score 0):

[Geekbench](https://www.geekbench.com/) is a widely used benchmark tool, available on macOS, Windows, Linux, iOS and Android. You can measure both CPU and GPU performance, and you can compare your results with other peopel who've uploaded their results on the [website](https://browser.geekbench.com/).

Another "cross platform" benchmark is MotionMark ([1.0](https://browserbench.org/MotionMark/) & [1.1](https://browserbench.org/MotionMark1.1/)) - however, it's intended to measure browser performance. While it's primarily used to, for example, compare Chrome to Firefox, you could compare Chrome's performance on Windows and on Linux.